# How to copy portion of the SOURCE image android - outOfMemoryError thrown out when trying to decode into bitmap

Tags: android, android-image

I'm trying to copy part of the source image. I've decoded the resource into bitmap with inScaling option turned off so I can crop from real image size but I'm getting outOfMemoryErorr thrown out.

I've read my device (S3) memory with

`Log.i("CropParams memory", String.valueOf(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()));`

and it's showing 64MB.

I would really like to crop from real image size and to know what exactly causes outOfMemoryError so I know how to manage this kind of situations. This particular image is 2448x3264 and has 3.41MB.

Why is this particular image causing this error?

Thanks

Comment: as a side note, the size of the file (3.41MB) is totally irrelevant. The actual size of the decoded image is 2448*3264*4 = ~32MB

Answer (score 0):

See [my answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26109455/594134%20%22my%20answer%20on%20another%20question) on how to dump the heap memory when you get an OutOfMemoryError.
With the Hprof file you should be able to analyze the memory usage as described [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think looks like a job for the Region decoder.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html

Just instantiate it with any of the newInstance api:s, then call decodeRegion for the region you are interested in.